# How to export all models in the same file with django-import-export?

Tags: django, export, django-import-export

I want to use django-import-export to manage export in my project.
But, I can figure out how to export all models in the same file with django-import-export

Can find in the doc a way to do that. I am only able to export model by model...

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an unusual way of handling the export.  I guess you would have one csv with all the rows together, perhaps in blocks delimited by the header row.

There isn't a default way of doing this with django-import-export, so you'd have to find a way to process all models sequentially and keep them in memory or write them to a temporary file, before exporting them in one large file.  You might be able to use the [`after_export()`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html?highlight=after_export#import_export.resources.Resource.after_export) hook for this.

If this is for the purpose of serializing all the db data, perhaps there are more suitable approaches, for example, [dumpscript](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpscript.html)?

Comment: Thanks for replying ; I will look dumpscript

Comment: np - please accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: it is not what I need ; In fact I have write code in my project that create a excel files with each spreedsheat representing each a model